# navigator.clipboard.writeText() не работает

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5

Есть `php`, он при определённых событиях выводит `button`.

```
printf('<button onclick="setclipboard()">Copy text</button>');
```

При нажатии на которую по идее должна срабатывать функция `setclipboard()`.

А вот и она:

```
<script>
function setclipboard(){
   navigator.clipboard.writeText("someText").then(function() {
//1
}, function() {
//2
   });
}
</script>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку копировался текст `"someText"`.

Но оно не работает. Почему? Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Можете чуть конкретней описать суть задачи? Текст "someText" копируется в буфер обмена. Что дальше Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: В описании метода, написано, что данная "возможность" еще не стабильная, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText , и что необходимо получить разрешение `clipboardWrite` на запись в буфер https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашелся.
Дело в том что на хостинге где проводились тесты был http протокол.
Судя по документации, для работы clipboard необходимо чтобы соединение было доверенным.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `setclipboard` видимо "не видна" из контекста вызова.

Попробуй так:

```
window.setclipboard = function () {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText("someText").then(function () {
//1
    }, function () {
//2
    });
};
```

Comment: Не помогло. :( Всё находится в одном php файле. Вот как это видит браузер: https://i.imgur.com/TMsRtc0.png

Comment: Может в браузере дело? navigator.clipboard в IE не поддерживается вроде как.

Comment: Chrome версия последняя

Comment: Мутная история. Давайте по порядку: если вы нажимаете кнопку Copy text и затем в каком нибудь текстовом редакторе вставляете текст с помощью Ctrl + V ничего не происходит? Текст не вставляется, someText не появляется?

Comment: Да, так и получается.

Answer (score 0):

Для примера (Есть, к примеру, поле ввода, или любое другое поле):

```
<?php
$bz = "1"; // К примеру, есть переменная.
?>
<div>Отсюда копируем текст</div>
<input id="textForCopy">
<?php
if ($bz == "1"){ // Выполняем проверку. Если переменная = 1, то показываем кнопку, которая копирует текст в буффер обмена.
    printf('<button onclick="setclipboard()">Copy text</button>');
}
?>
<div>Сюда вставляем текст из буффера</div>
<input>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function setclipboard(){
        let text = document.getElementById('textForCopy').value; // получаем введённый в поле текст
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() { // Копируем текст в буффер обмена
//1
        }, function() {
//2
        });
    }
</script>
```

Как это работает, когда есть кнопка:

```js
    function setclipboard(){
        let text = document.getElementById('textForCopy').value;
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function() {
//1
        }, function() {
//2
        });
    }
```

```html
<div>Отсюда копируем текст</div>
<input id="textForCopy">
<button onclick="setclipboard()">Copy text</button>
<div>Сюда вставляем текст из буффера (Ctrl + v)</div>
<input>
```

Comment: У меня это точно так же и работает, только кнопка выводится в цикле.(их много) И текст у меня берётся не из поля на странице а из БД. Но это не работает, при нажатии ничего не происходит.

Comment: @bully Это пример. А чего Вы ждёте??? Вы так и не ответили на вопрос. Вы копируете данные в буффер обмена, дальше что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Мне нужно скопировать данные в буфер обмена компьютера. Затем я их могу вставить в текстовик, в другой софт и т.д. Главная задача это скопировать текст из переменной в буфер обмена компьютера.

Comment: @bully Ну так Вы их и копируете. Вот пример выше наглядно это демонстрирующий.

Comment: @bully в чём проблема? Попробуйте в примере ввести текст в первое поле, нажмите кнопку `copy text` и проверьте. Текст будет скопирован в буффер обмена. Вставляйте куда хотите.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WkfSkcB.png Проверил, вот это выдаёт. Причем это выдаёт именно на хостинге, если тестировать на localhost всё отрабатывает нормально. Проверил 2 хостинга, везде так.